# How to get specific field using grpc interceptor in spring + kotlin?

Tags: spring, kotlin, grpc

```
class MyInterceptor: ServerInterceptor {
    override fun <ReqT : Any?, RespT : Any?> interceptCall(
        call: ServerCall<ReqT, RespT>?,
        headers: Metadata?,
        next: ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT>?
    ): ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> {


       return next!!.startCall(call, headers)
        
    }
}
```

I have this method.
What I want is

1. Check if ownerId field exists
2. Check ownerId is valid
3. If it is not valid -> not pass to the next call
4. If it is valid -> pass to the next call

Thank you in advance..